# Overloading LDAP

Tags: ldap

In my college there's an LDAP server managed by the staff. We can use this LDAP server from our machines, but cannot modify attributes (eg: user login shell).

We'd like to modify these attributes, so we were thinking of setting up an LDAP server working as a proxy for the other one: we would set any attribute we need on our LDAP server, and then use the one offered by the staff for authentication.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is `replication`. Arrange for the administrators of the LDAP server to have its contents replicated to your local LDAP server. They might refuse, since the database could diverge if the replication is not `multi-master` or bi-directional. Failing this, configure your own LDAP server and populate with data as required and configure your LDAP clients to use the new server.

Answer (score 0):

This is what OpenLDAP's overlay [slapo-translucent](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-translucent) was designed for. Basically you're maintaining a local database in your LDAP proxy backend augmenting content retrieved from your company's LDAP server.

See also: [OpenLDAP Admin Guide -- Translucent Proxy](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Translucent%20Proxy)

For simple cases like *homeDirectory* I'd suggest to look at what the NSS/PAM clients like *sssd* and *nss-pam-ldapd* provide for special attribute mappings. This might already be sufficient.